# Angular 4 : window:scroll works but not scroll listener on image

Tags: javascript, html, angular, scroll

I am a new bee , who is trying to develop small application , which allows  to zoom using mouse scroll on the image.

```
<img  (window:scroll)="onScroll($event) .....></img>
```

Above code works perfectly but the problem is that it detects the scroll of whole document.

So i tried with  `(scroll)="onScroll($event)"` and it did not worked.

I am using Angular JS 4 Framework.

Could you explain , why its not working and a way to achieve my purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as Angular JS 4.
It's either AngularJS or Angular(2, 4, 5...).

Anyway, you should probably stop event bubbling in your onScroll event handler like so:

```
onScroll(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // event.preventDefatult();
}
```

You should read up on the topic, here are the basics:

https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing